# Question about a direct consequence of the Rank-Nullity Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a question about a direct consequence of the Rank-Nullity Theorem.

Specifically, if $A_{\phi}$ is the transformation matrix of $\phi$ with respect to an ordered basis and $dim(Im(\phi)) < dim(V)$, then the system of linear equations $A_{\phi}x = 0$ has infinitely many solutions.

I was unable to find a proof for this claim, so my questions is: how is this a direct consequence of the Rank-Nullity Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\dim (\operatorname{im}\phi) < \dim V$ implies that $\dim(\ker \phi) = \dim V - \dim (\operatorname{im}\phi) >0$ and then there is a nonzero $v \in V$ such that $\phi(v) = 0$, that is, $A_\phi [v] = 0$, where $[v]$ is the associated column vector (with respecto to the ordered basis) to $v$. It follows that *any* scalar multiple of $[v]$ is also a solution of $A_\phi x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption means that the *nullity*, the dimension of the kernel, is at least one.  Thus the null space, or kernel, is at least one-dimensional.  But a vector space over $\Bbb F$ of dimension k has cardinality $|\Bbb F|^k$.  Hence is infinite in case $\Bbb F$ is infinite.